# getting error when to call REST web service

Tags: rest, api, sugarcrm, sugarorm

I am using SUGARCRM 6.5* and sending post request with the following structure:

```
host:http://test.newcrm.loc
path:/service/v4_1/rest.php
method:login
input_type:JSON
response_type:JSON
rest_data:{"user_auth":{"user_name":"admin","password":"admin","version":"1"},"application_name":"SugarCRM REST API"}
```

However, I am getting following error :

> {"user_auth":{"user_name":"admin","password":"admin","version":"1"},"application_name":"SugarCRM
>   REST API"}

password and username is correct. I have searched internet and did not find answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was i did not put password in md5 format. Therefore, it returned error message as stated above.